# Trying to run discord bot on ec2 and this error happened

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, discord.js

I am trying to run discord bot on amazon ec2, I made npm install, then I tried to run node . for test and this error poped up [node . error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2t6S.png) then I noticed that when running npm install this pops up [npm install warns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDBh0.png). Please help!

Comment: Your version of Node.js is out of date.

In the future, try not to use images. If possible copy and paste the error code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your node version is out of date.

You can:

- update node version (for example using [n package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n))
- transpile your code to es standard that can be handled with your version of node

Answer (score 0):

You need minimum node.js v12 for running discord.js version v12

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I updated version.